# How to create batch file or script to create multipe shortcuts to EXE's

Tags: windows-10, batch, shortcuts

Hello I have about 122 folders with exe's in all of them that match the name of the folder. Is there a way to write a script to create a shortcut for each exe within the folders and without the 'shortcut' tag. Just trying to avoid doing it 1 by 1 manually with some clever scripting...

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: Forgot to mention.... Windows 10

Comment: also I menltioned removing shortcut tag, but would also like to add the extinsion *.lnk (this way i can do a wild card search for these and select them all accordingly)

Comment: my answer should accomplish what you need to do - when you script a shortcut it doesn't add that `- shortcut` the way the GUI does; no need to edit your registry or mess with your other settings. if you'd like the shortcuts placed it different folders, or only create shortcuts if they match the folder name, that's all doable too - just let us know what works for you.

Comment: @drewjbx: I know this is old, but *all* valid shourtcuts have the `.lnk` extension, it's just "superHidden" -- ignoring your **Explorer** view settings. This is set via the presence of the registry value `NeverShowExt` under `HKCR\lnkfile`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem must be run in a window with admin privileges
rem windows 10 cmd batch file to create a hard shortcut to all .exe files on a volume if placed in the root folder; 
rem in a folder and all subfolders if not placed in the root folder. the shortcut is created in the folder where the .exe is.
rem the "shortcut" extension should not be part of the filename.  the .lnk extension should be part of the filename.  
rem links that already exist to .exe files should be deleted.
rem see mklink /? and https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html
rem mklink saveShortcutAs targetOfShortcut
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions
rem begin turn off shortcut name extension
rem see https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4663-shortcut-name-extension-turn-off-windows-10-a.html
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" /V link /T REG_Binary /D 00000000 /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates" /V ShortcutNameTemplate /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
rem end turn off shortcut name extension
rem the following command deletes all links to .exe files.          
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /s *.exe.lnk') DO del "%%a"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /s *.exe') DO mklink /h "%%a.lnk" "%%a"
exit /b
```

see mklink /?

see [ss64.com mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

see cmd /?

see for /?

see dir /?

see [ss64.com for in do](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

see [turn off / on shortcut name extension](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4663-turn-off-shortcut-name-extension-windows-10-a.html)

see [Symbolic Links, Hard Links and Directory Junctions in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/symbolic-link-in-windows-10/)

Build a windows 10 cmd batch file that must be run in a window with admin privileges that will create a hard shortcut to every .exe file on a volume if placed in the root folder, and every .exe file in a folder and all subfolders if not placed in the root. the "shortcut" extension should not be part of the filename.  the .lnk extension should be part of the filename.  links that already exist to .exe files should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I obviously know nothing about coding, I took your code and pasted to a text file, renamed to *.bat. Placed in the root folder of the 122 folders I want to create shortcuts for. Ran batch as admin, command window popped and things were being done, then explorer closed. Checked in the folders and didn't see a shortcut created. Do I need to put in my own values somewhere in your script or ?

Comment: run `cmd /k dir *.lnk` in one of the folders where you created a link.  explorer does not show the .lnk extension.

Comment: I am making some changes to the code. I'll comment again when I want you to run it.

Comment: I created symbolic links by not using the /h argument so I've added a command to the batch to delete the shortcuts you just created and the command to create the links will now create hard links. you only need to run the commands in the "turn off shortcut name extension" section once so comment those lines with **rem**

Comment: so yes the *.lnk doesn't show in windows (shows in a command prompt though). I am using 3 test folders. New Folder (Root) -> folder1, folder2, folder3. There is an EXE in each of the 3 folders. I placed the batch file with updated code into root (New Folder). Ran it, still don't see a created shortcut. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you don't see the shortcut in explorer not windows.

Comment: in explorer you will not see the .lnk extension. you will see a shortcut created that has a "arrow" icon.  the .lnk extension is there and you can search for it.

Comment: not sure what you mean seeing it in explorer not windows. I am using windows explorer to view file contents of the folders with EXE's. Don't see any other files that were created, Am I looking in the wrong place for these shortcut files?

Comment: if you are "using windows explorer to view file contents of the folders with EXE's" stop looking for EXE's.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to method for shortcut creation is to create a temporary VB script within batch. Your solution may look something like this:

```
@echo off

set "des=C:\Where\You\Want\The\Shortcuts"
set "src=C:\Root\Folder\Of\Executables"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%src%" %%A in (*.exe) do (
    set "exe=%%A"
    set "name=%%~nA"

    set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) >> !SCRIPT!
    echo sLinkFile = "%des%\!name!.lnk" >> !SCRIPT!
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^) >> !SCRIPT!
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "!exe!" >> !SCRIPT!
    echo oLink.Save >> !SCRIPT!

    cscript /nologo !SCRIPT!
    del !SCRIPT!

)
```

This sets variables for both where you want your shortcuts (`des` - i.e. if you want them on your `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` or some other folder) and where your executables are located (`src`). We have to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` so we can use variables in our for-loop - which is: `for` all executables (`*.exe`) located in our `src` directory, set the fully qualified path of the .exe as `exe`, and then set the name of the .exe as `name` (does not include extension). The next part is the VB script - we set `SCRIPT` as some randomly named .vbs file in our TEMP folder, then we echo our VBS commands into that script, run it, and delete it. This will happen for each iteration of your for-loop until it has created a shortcut for each executable.

Important things to note about the VBS lines: `sLinkFile` determines where your shortcut is created and what it is called; `oLink.TargetPath` references the full path of your executable; `!`'s are used instead of `%`'s for variables in the for-loop; and when we echo the parentheses into the VBS file they have to be escaped with a `^`. Hopefully this does exactly what you want it to - should only require you to set the `des` and `src` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Can't resist posting the **PowerShell** version:

```
$TopFolder = 'C:\FolderWithExeSubfolders'

Get-ChildItem -Path $TopFolder -Filter *.exe -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $WSHshell = New-Object -com wscript.shell
} -Process {
    ### Using the folder name as the base name for the shortcut. This allows you the
    ###    option of giving the folder a "display name" to be used.
    $NewLnkPath             = '{0}\{1}.lnk' -f $_.DirectoryName, $_.Directory.Name
    $NewShortcut            = $WSHshell.CreateShortcut($NewLnkPath)
    $NewShortcut.TargetPath = $_.FullName

    ### Optional
    ### $NewShortcut.Arguments        = <string>
    ### $NewShortcut.Description      = <string>
    ### $NewShortcut.Hotkey           = <string>
    ### $NewShortcut.IconLocation     = <string>
    ### $NewShortcut.WindowStyle      = <1|2|7>
    ### $NewShortcut.WorkingDirectory = <string>

    $NewShortcut.Save()
} -End {}
```