# Loop through .bat location's subfolders, create shortcuts for each .exe, add highest subfolder prefix, save to specified folder

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

As the title says, but [here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eenAt.png) for a visual explanation.

I like the idea of doing this via a batch script. (as I am somewhat familiar with batch scripts and find them quite readable, so that way I can more easily make changes and/or re-use code in the future)

However, I am not opposed to other hybrid solutions or a different solution entirely. The one requirement I do have is that it must run on modern Windows computers without requiring additional installs beyond updates.

Below you can find my current code ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1441188)), but please note that this does not yet meet all my criteria as I ran out of both batch and google-fu skills:

```
@echo off

set "des=%~dp0\_shortcuts"
set "src=%~dp0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%src%" %%A in (*.exe) do (
    set "exe=%%A"
    set "name=%%~nA"

    set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) >> !SCRIPT!
    echo sLinkFile = "%des%\!name!.lnk" >> !SCRIPT!
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^) >> !SCRIPT!
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "!exe!" >> !SCRIPT!
    echo oLink.Save >> !SCRIPT!

    cscript /nologo !SCRIPT!
    del !SCRIPT!

)
PAUSE
```

With the above code, I am getting an error like below for each shortcut it tries to create:

> C:\Users\mica\AppData\Local\Temp\24172-1508-16791-17305.vbs(5, 1) WshShortcut.Save: Unable to save shortcut "C:\Users\mica\OneDrive\Documents_create shortcuts_shortcuts\in-test1-folder.lnk".

I gather it's an elevation issue, so I tried to implement [this code](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-elevate.html) to fix the issue, but I was unsuccessful.

If anyone can help complete the code or has better solutions, please do share! Also, do let me know if I forgot to mention anything.

Comment: Does it have to be shortcuts? What about symbolic links with the mklink tool?

Comment: Can you remove the "del !SCRIPT!" part and show what the vbs looks like from inside?